# "To lose grip on X" or "to lose grip of X?"

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

I'm confused because searching the phrase yields more or less the same results on Google Books:

[lose grip on the](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=RH2LW_nsGoy2ggfp8KzoCQ&q=%22lose%20grip%20on%20the%20%22&oq=%22lose%20grip%20on%20the%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2797.2850.0.3075.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.mv_2-JaquOY)

[lose grip of the](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=SH2LW4K-Eeu0ggfxloqQDA&q=%22lose%20grip%20of%20the%20%22&oq=%22lose%20grip%20of%20the%20%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...167714.167795.0.167926.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0....0.W_9-wGfoc2s)

Which alternative is correction? Or maybe both are correct?

Example sentence:

When the train started off, she lost grip of the standing pole she was grabbing.

Comment: A fine point. To **grab** is to reach out towards something and seize it. The participle **grabbing** would suggest an attempt to grab in progress, that her grip on the pole had not been fully established. She cannot lose a grip she hasn't got yet.  In any case, you don't really need "she was grabbing" as you already have "grip".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[lose your grip](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/lose-your-grip)***  is an expression which is used literally but also figuratively. Dictionaries shows in both cases the use of the preposition ***on***, but evidence from  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lose%20grip%20on%2C%20lose%20grip%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Close%20grip%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Close%20grip%20of%3B%2Cc0) suggests that both ***on*** and ***of*** are commonly used.

> to become less confident and less able to deal with a situation
>
> • He began a forlorn final game by losing his grip on the racket altogether.
>
> • Half way through, the film loses its grip on the day-to-day reality in Northern Ireland.
>
> • Unfortunately, lately her mother seems to have lost her grip on reality.

(Longman Dictionary)

***[lose your grip (on something):](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lose-your-grip-on-something)***

> to become less able to understand things or deal with them
>
> - Are you starting to lose your grip on reality?

MacMillan Dictionary

- When the train started off, she lost grip of/on the standing pole she was grabbing